# Open Info Activity without closing Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm making a simple android application with two activities. one MainActivity and one InfoActivity. I have a button on my ActionBar and on click I want to open my InfoActivity. In my InfoActivity I have a back button, that removes my InfoActivity and open my MainActivity again. Can I open the InfoActivity without closing my MainActivity?

I'm parsing JSON from internet my Main Activity, and I don't want it to load everything again when I close the InfoActivity.

Code for opening InfoActivity:

```
  private View.OnClickListener onInfoBtnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

Code for closing InfoActivity in InfoActivity class:

```
private View.OnClickListener onBackBtnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(InfoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Comment: in your back button click put finish(); instead of intent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Can I open the InfoActivity without closing my MainActivity?**

No, the InfoActivity will be called to the foreground and MainActivity in the background, because it will be in the state `stopped`. The problem is if you fire the Intent in your InfoActivity like this, there will be a new instance of the MainActivity besides the old instance.

Add a flag to your Intent call to prevent a new instance of the MainActivity. Then it will be called from the stack.

```
private View.OnClickListener onBackBtnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(InfoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Or simple call `finish()`, like hamad and Aerrow suggested. Then the InfoActivity will be destroyed and the MainActivity will be called from the stack.

Answer (score 2):

start info activity using

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

and in infoactivity just call `finish()` on button click do not start activity again.then you will get back to previous activity