# Reuse the Activity, without re-creating it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm making an Android app for a School.

1st activity is of **Student** which contain a ViewPager consists of 3 Fragments. This activity is expensive to load as it contains 3 Fragments.

1st Fragment contain a ListView of Games

2nd Fragment contain a ListView of Cartoons

3rd Fragment contain a ListView of Test (ListView contain Only Title of Test).

Now in **Test** Fragment onClick on of test (displayed in listview) a new **ShowTest** Activity is open which displayed the complete test.

Every thing working fine.

That's the code in TestFragment to start ShowTest Activity

```
test.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent it = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowTest.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
```

And in ShowTest Activity I'm just calling finish();

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
}
```

But in **ShowTest** when onBackpressed() is called **Student** activity re-creates (Every thing in fragments reload). I don't want this activity to be created 2nd time. As it expensive to load.

These two links didn't helped me

[Open Info Activity without closing Main Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154760/open-info-activity-without-closing-main-activity)

[Android - Relaunching an activity without having to re-create it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792372/android-relaunching-an-activity-without-having-to-re-create-it)

Your Help will be appreciated.

Thanks (Edited)

Comment: this depends in how you start your activity and where the relevant part of code is. For example, if you finish the activity and go the next, and from that back to the first one, then it´s recreated. If you doesn´t finish, usually the activity stays in the background. Then it´s important where all the code is....if you initalize for example everything in onResume(), then all will be done again. You definitely have to read Activities Lifecycle:https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: THere's no way to assure this.  If Android detects memory issues, it will close out activities that are not in the foreground and recreate them again later when needed.  There's no way to override that behavior (in fact the only option is to turn it on all the time, for testing).

Comment: Post the code that you use to start the ShowTestActivity, your onBackPressed() method and any other relevant code.

Comment: @MateusGondim I edited my question.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I'm not finishing the Student Activity and also not initializing  any thing onResume()

Comment: Are you overriding onStart() or onResume() in Student Activity or in the fragments?

Comment: I guess it doesn´t reload, I think that you just think it releoads because it needs long time. I guess the problem is another and you are looking in the wrong place. Please post the code from your activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, My mistake

In Android Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="plan9.naseemdev.muhammadtaimoor.naseem.Student"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```

Due to  '
android:noHistory="true" '
Student activity was re-creating every time.
After removing this line it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might be calling `finish()` on start of other activity. Dont call that and start activity without finish().

Comment: No. I'm not calling 'finish()' on start of activity.
Still curious why this is happening

Answer (score -2):

Share your code so that i can help further.
Also please check you are initializing the pager adapter properly.